# Changing table row height and adding more data in the row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need to have a html table where I click on one of the values in any row, then that entire row should expand (up or down with slide animation would be nice) and I need to insert a chart inside the row.

How should I do this using jQuery, also I would probably need to have the chart in a separate file and include the file in the dive in the row or some better container for the chart?

Comment: I have tried like a js function call onclick of the row value and in the function I am trying to do $(this).closest('tr').height('100'). Thats not working.

Comment: If you add content to a table cell the row will automatically expand.. Not sure why you need to set the height.  You can add the data and do a fadeIn or slideOut on that data.

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip, but I would have the data in a div and where would I place or put this div on click? inside on of the columns? I want the data to replace the existing contents of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  My example uses a button but you could put the click event on anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Y4nC8/2/

Here is an example

```
<table>
 <tr><td>Col</td><td>Col</td><td><button>Add stuff</button></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Col</td><td>Col</td><td><button>Add stuff</button></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Col</td><td>Col</td><td><button>Add stuff</button></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Col</td><td>Col</td><td><button>Add stuff</button></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Col</td><td>Col</td><td><button>Add stuff</button></td></tr>
</table>​
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $newstuff = $('<div>my data<br />more data <br /> ok good</div>');
    $newstuff.appendTo($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)')).slideDown();

  });    
});
```

​

Comment: This is very close to what I want I just want to have a close button on the expanded row which will slide up the row again and display the previous contents. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Adding a close button is pretty easy.. You'd just `$('btn').click(function() { $(this).closest('div').slideUp(); });`